# Как при приходи из одной Activity в другую Activity с bottom navigation view открыть нужную вкладку?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

В Activity2 есть bottom navigation view с пятью вкладками, при нажатии на каждую из них открывается определенный fragment. При переходе из Activity1 в Activity2 открывается первая вкладка с fragment1. После чего открываем вторую вкладку с fragment2. Во fragment2 при нажатию на кнопку переходим в Activity3. По нажатию navigation icon в toolbar, который находится в Activity3, переходим обратно в Activity2 и открывается первая вкладка с fragment1, а нужно чтобы открывалась вторая вкладка с fragment2.

Activity1.class:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

        btnDone.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnDone:
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
       }
    }
}
```

Activity2.class:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, new Fragment1())
                .commit();
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.action_one:
                        fragment = new Fragment1();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_two:
                        fragment = new Fragment2();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_tree:
                        fragment = new Fragment3();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_four:
                        fragment = new Fragment4();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_five:
                        fragment = new Fragment5();
                        break;
                }
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Fragment2.class:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

Button btnNext;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                             startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity3.class));
                        }
                    });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Activity3.class:

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_leggins);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю в вашем случае достаточно переписать setNavigationOnClickListener в Activity3 используя onBackPressed.

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```